# Searching for a letter within a list

Tags: python, list, search, letters

I'm very new to coding and am taking an online course at the moment. Using the CodeHS sandbox to make programs and having a bit of a hard time with this one. I am trying to make my program look through this list of names and return which ones have the letter "E" / "e" in them. I also want it to keep count of how many names are being found and eventually return that count. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance. Here is my code so far:

```
middle_names = ["Michael", "Abdallah", "Parvati", "Sanskriti", "Piper", "Samuel", "Lee", "Meg", "Michael", "Mohamed", "Sofia", "Ahmed Hani", "Josh", "Lawrence", "Mireya", "Mingyue", "Bradley Theodore", "McKenna", "Ali"]


def search():
    if "e" in middle_names:
        print middle_names

search()
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! It worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Use python's sweet list comprehension, which will return you a list containing all the names that have "e" in them like -

```
middle_name_contains_e = [i for i in middle_names if 'e' in i]
```

and as pointed out in the comment, just replace 'e' with 'E' to match capital letter like so -

```
middle_name_contains_e = [i for i in middle_names if 'E' in i]
```

Or you could manually loop through all the names in the list like so -

```
def middle_name_contains_e():
    names = []
    for name in middle_names:
        if "e" in name:
            names.append(name)
    return names
names = middle_name_contains_e()
```

Comment: and adjust to `[i for i in middle_names if 'e' in i or 'E' in i]` if case insensitive :) ah list comprehensions so sweet

Answer (score 0):

#### Loop approaches

You need to cycle through each item in your list. This is commonly achieved via a `for` loop:

```
def search(lst, k):
    for item in lst:
        if 'e' in item:
            print(item)

search(middle_names, 'e')
```

A couple of ways you can improve such an algorithm is to account for lower or upper case letters, e.g. via `str.casefold`, and use `return` or `yield` statements to have the function give an output. Here's an example using a generator:

```
def search(lst, k):
    for item in lst:
        if 'e' in item.casefold():
            yield item

for res in search(middle_names, 'e'):
    print(res)
```

#### Comprehensions

One Pythonic and efficient approach is to use a list comprehension:

```
res = [item for item in middle_names if 'e' in item.casefold()]
print(res)
```

Or, if you want a lazy approach, you can use a generator comprehension:

```
res = (item for item in middle_names if 'e' in item.casefold())
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this to calculate count & letters with e in one function:

```
def search(x):
    e_list = []
    for i in x:
        if 'e' in i:
            e_list.append(i)
    return len(e_list), e_list

count,e_list = search(middle_names)
# count = 13
# e_list = ['Michael', 'Piper', 'Samuel', 'Lee', 'Meg', 'Michael', 'Mohamed', 'Ahmed Hani', 'Lawrence', 'Mireya', 'Mingyue', 'Bradley Theodore', 'McKenna']
```

Comment: Why do we need a separate counter? List length `len(e_list)` should suffice?